# NSString sizeWithAttributes Crash on iOS 12

Tags: objective-c, crash, ios12

I recently encountered a strange Crash when using a lyrics component. Language is Objective-C. This stupid crash has been bothering me for many days...

Here's the code:

```
CGFloat charWidth = [character.character sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:displayFont}].width;
```

and my crash log stack:

```
0 CoreText 0x0000000234f09938 __ZNK12TSplicedFont23GetOpticalSizeComponentEd + 148
1 CoreText 0x0000000234e7ffcc __ZL28DerivedOpticalFontDescriptorPK18__CTFontDescriptorPK9TBaseFontd + 120
2 CoreText 0x0000000234e88008 __ZN12TFontCascade26InitCascadeFallbackAtIndexElRj + 252
3 CoreText 0x0000000234e87a70 __ZNK12TFontCascade14CreateFallbackEPK8__CTFontPK10__CFString13CTEmojiPolicy + 728
4 CoreText 0x0000000234e54e40 __ZN13TGlyphEncoder21AppendUnmappedCharRunEjR6TCFRefIP5CTRunEPK8__CTFontR7CFRangeS8_R10TGlyphListI18TDeletedGlyphIndexESD_RK12TFontCascadeNS_15ClusterMatchingEb + 704
5 CoreText 0x0000000234e54900 __ZN13TGlyphEncoder28RunUnicodeEncoderRecursivelyEjO6TCFRefIP5CTRunEPK8__CTFont7CFRangeR10TGlyphListI18TDeletedGlyphIndexESC_PK12TFontCascadeNS_15ClusterMatchingEb + 1900
6 CoreText 0x0000000234e54114 __ZN13TGlyphEncoder17RunUnicodeEncoderEO6TCFRefIP5CTRunEPK8__CTFont7CFRangeR10TGlyphListI18TDeletedGlyphIndexEPK12TFontCascade + 128
7 CoreText 0x0000000234e53c30 __ZN13TGlyphEncoder11EncodeCharsE7CFRangeRK11TAttributesNS_9FallbacksE + 1240
8 CoreText 0x0000000234e6acb0 __ZN21TTypesetterAttrString10InitializeEPK20__CFAttributedString + 304
9 CoreText 0x0000000234e6ab6c __ZN21TTypesetterAttrStringC2EPK20__CFAttributedStringPK14__CFDictionary + 200
10 CoreText 0x0000000234e58070 CTLineCreateWithAttributedString + 60
11 UIFoundation 0x000000023b72be2c -[NSCoreTypesetter _stringDrawingCoreTextEngineWithOriginalString:rect:padding:context:forceClipping:styledTextOptions:attributes:stringDrawingOptions:drawingContext:wantsTextLineFragments:validatedAttributedString:firstNonRenderedCharacterIndex:foundSoftHyphenAtEOL:enginePathUsed:] + 1344
12 UIFoundation 0x000000023b7aae38 ___NSStringDrawingEngine + 3104
13 UIFoundation 0x000000023b72eb04 -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 160
14 UIFoundation 0x000000023b7307dc -[NSString(NSStringDrawing) sizeWithAttributes:] + 120
```

Comment: could you please edit the way you are showing log. It will be easy for us to understand what is happening.

Comment: log has been edited, Thx~

Comment: as [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1531844-sizewithattributes?language=objc#discussion) said, you must raise charWidth to the nearest higher integer using the ceil function, did you do that?

Comment: Guys, I have fix this issue. this method must called in main thread

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this issue. this method must called in main thread – JethroYe